# IPhone: Missed Calls icon

Tags: iphone, icons, standard-icons

Anybody knows if exist any way to show the phone calls icons (generated, received and missed calls) from the standard SDK, like the iphone phone calls application.

Take a look to this screenshot:

- http://www.iclarified.com/images/news/2052/8690/8690.jpg

Anybody knows if it's posible?

Thank you,

Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to access those built-in icons. You could use your own icon images with a similar appearance, if necessary.

Comment: This is my actual solution... Thanks for your answer Anomie